# How to develop an E-commerce website using Python and Django as a server side language

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I want to build an E-commerce website using Bootstrap, HTML, CSS, Java script in Frontend and For backend I want to use Python, Django and MongoDB. Can I get step wise instruction to develop files of codes of each language and how to link each one of them to make fully functional website.

I want to know what directories and files will get added in code editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the standard Django monolithic approach, which means creating a Django project using `django-admin startproject project_name`. Here, you can configure your templates, static files, and media. You can use the bootstrap CDN  or [bootstrap compiled CSS and JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js). You can create Django apps for specific logic within your web application.